# get probabilities using some data to fit normal distribution with R

Tags: r, distribution

i got this data and i need to fit a normal distribution to get another set of data associated with probabilities of ocurrence.

```
data = c(150,94.1,127.6,77.2,136.1,83.4,75.6,92.7,106.5,95.9,112.1,90.4,143.7,152.7,113.3,143.9,87.9,85.2,117.2,193,153.7,84.7,97.3,140.3,80,103.6,72.6,90.7,52.6,52.8)
```

and then the probability of occurence:

```
returntime = c(1.02,1.5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20,25,30,50,100,200,500,1000,5000,10000) #years
prob_returntime = 1/returntime #need to get the data associated with this prob.
```

i have tried to use qnorm(), but i think i'm doing something wrong...

expected output:

[image]

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you are asking. You first write that you are looking for  probabilities, and then  you also state that you want to use a `quantile` function which is the **inverse** of the cumulative distribution function. Please add the expected output to your question.

Comment: hey, i made an edit. pls take a look. but yes, i need the inverse of cdf. @Base_R_Best_R

Comment: Are you trying to find an association between rainfall and "return time" (whatever that is)?  It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here, and you may be leading yourself (and everyone else) over a cliff by pre-declaring that it involves quantiles of a normal distribution.

Comment: Okay, I've been looking at your data and it doesn't make sense to me.  First, you're not trying to predict rainfall based on rt or rt-inverse, because you have 30 observations and 22 values of rt.  Second, how on earth do you view the inverse of time (measured in years in your comments) as a probability?  To misquote Ricky Ricardo talking to Lucille Ball, "Lucy, you got some splainin' to do!"

Comment: Maybe could help to explain a little bit more on the working done here as an introduction to explain the situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the quantiles of the normal distribution corresponding to `data` but for the values of `1 - prob_returntime` we can do the following.

**Code**

```
# Estimate mean and standard deviation from your data
mu <- mean(data)
std <- sd(data)

# then use qnorm to get quantiles of data associated with return prob

data.frame("return_time" = returntime, "probability" = 1/returntime,
           "data value" = qnorm(1 - (1 / returntime), mu, std))
   

#    return_time probability data.value
# 1         1.02  0.98039216   38.94683
# 2         1.50  0.66666667   92.69954
# 3         2.00  0.50000000  106.89333 
# 4         3.00  0.33333333  121.08712
# 5         4.00  0.25000000  129.11985
# 6         5.00  0.20000000  134.62735
# 7         6.00  0.16666667  138.77285
# 8         7.00  0.14285714  142.07307
# 9         8.00  0.12500000  144.80089
# 10        9.00  0.11111111  147.11719
# 11       10.00  0.10000000  149.12440
# 12       15.00  0.06666667  156.35874
# 13       20.00  0.05000000  161.09633
# 14       25.00  0.04000000  164.58383
# 15       30.00  0.03333333  167.32647
# 16       50.00  0.02000000  174.57069
# 17      100.00  0.01000000  183.55366
# 18      200.00  0.00500000  191.77484
# 19      500.00  0.00200000  201.73763
# 20     1000.00  0.00100000  208.72601
# 21     5000.00  0.00020000  223.55000
# 22    10000.00  0.00010000  229.44638
```

Comment: yeah, but something is wrong, because a higher value of data have a bigger return_time. Data corresponds to rainfall in (mm)

Comment: The quantiles we are looking at here are corresponding to the probability (1/returntime). A high probability  yields a high value. Essentially we are asking if the data was normally distributed with `mean()` and `sd()` of *data* what is the value for which 98% of the data would be smaller or equal to that value. Accordingly, high probability values yield quantiles that are far to the right of the mean.

Comment: in excel this was made by (mean + (Z * sd)). Can you relate this operation to some function in R?

Comment: @Bryan Souza what is `Z` ?

Comment: "Z Score" Z = (value – mean)/ (Standard Deviation).

Comment: i found the answer. we need to use (1 - prob) to make that. tks for the help !